# Create matrix out of two lists while populating body of matrix using custom method in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists that I would like to use to make a 2D matrix. I would like to call a custom method based on the combination of the two lists to populate the body of the matrix.

How would I do this?

Say I have a list of [A, B, C] and [1, 2, 3]. The result I want would be:

```
  A B C
1 x
2
3
```

where x is the return of my_method(A,1).

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. What do you mean that it is "the result I want"? Do you want a printout, just replacing the character `x` with the return of your method? Or do you mean a returned data structure, such as a matrix? I see no matrix in what you show.

Comment: Sorry, first time user. I would like a printout replacing x with the return of my method, in the format of a two dimensional matrix using the lists as lables/headers along x and y axis...

Comment: I still do not understand. Please give a minimal and *complete* example showing what you want. Also show the work you have done so far, your attempted code, and a statement of what is not working. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have:

```
xs = ["A", "B", "C"]
ys = [1, 2, 3]
```

Let's take a simple example: `f` repeats `y` times the char `x`

```
f=lambda x,y:x*y
```

The computation of the matrix is obvious: for each `y`, we compute a row of `f(x,y)` with all `x` in `xs`.

```
matrix = [[f(x,y) for x in xs] for y in ys]
print ("matrix", matrix)
```

The display of the matrix is more interesting. First, we need to compute the width of each column. 
The width of a column is the width of its widest element. If `col` is the column, the width is `max(len(str(z)) for z in col)`.
The first column is the `ys`. To get the columns of the matrix, we just zip every row: `zip(*matrix)` is the same as `zip(row[0], row[1], ...)`

```
ws = [max(len(str(y)) for y in ys)] + [max(len(str(y)) for y in col) for col in zip(*matrix)]
print ("ws", ws)
```

Now, we can print the matrix. The first row is `[" "]+xs`, the following rows are `[y]+row` where `y` is the label of the row. We get the labels and the rows with a new `zip`: `zip(ys, matrix)`.
We have our rows, and we zip the values with the width of the columns (another `zip`! `zip(zs, ws)`) to adjust (`ljust`) the columns. The tab separates the columns:

```
for zs in ([" "]+xs, *[[y]+row for y, row in zip(ys, matrix)]): 
    print ("\t".join([str(z).ljust(w) for z,w in zip(zs, ws)]))
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C  
1   A   B   C  
2   AA  BB  CC 
3   AAA BBB CCC
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY7NbsMgEITvPMWKE9goUpNbpByaPAbl4Ka1SmSDxRLx8/IumDTtqRzQzmp2vlmS/7LmsK4R4QSSvlIB9Fy/C1UkbcsXAXsBB0XG0zTM7x8DRJGOsUtkHrzTsXrkyMqSw2gdRNAGIqpNpCoSKrI4bTww2m4KoQ2ckLBR5iGy6dMw9I4lzv8ecwX9P4arnZoqQ9VZL6x7pP9yAxZmwMKr1ozVySSlqo8ooJMyqd7Z0GIF1PGRlfBZVvEjECjvJ/XN093NasNkrZX5brrd0bPQCmXxDMm40RXn6/oN)

Comment: jferard - thank you! this worked. I'll need to study up on zip() .... seems very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
list2 = [1, 2, 3]

matrix = []
for item1 in list1:
   row = []
   for item2 in list2:
       row.append(my_method(item1, item2))
   matrix.append(row)
```